# How to approach time series regression with one continuous variable and one logistical variable?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression

I am working in R with daily time series data and have daily observations of two variables. The first is continuous.  The second is zero for every day except one, in which it is a number (*I'm not sure what to call it, so I referred to it as “almost-Boolean” in my title*).  Both variables are stationary.  I have hundreds of observations to work with, but I have put together a month of sample data:

```
d <- (as.Date("2000-01-01"):as.Date("2000-01-30"))
x <- c(19,31,47,65,42,55,43,69,38,57,85,70,38,42,50,40,35,69,48,37,41,32,39,41,58,43,
     32,25,22,30)
z <- c( 0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0,0)
data <- data.frame(date=as.Date(d),x = as.integer(x),z = as.integer(z))
```

For a given vector y(t), what is the best approach/package to test whether variables x(t) and z(t)  (and their lagged values) are predictive of y(t), either together or independently?  Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Often times the "best" approach is not the most *sophisticated* model but rather the *simplest*. Why don't you start with a regular, run-of-the-mill ordinary least squares regression and then go from there (i.e. use **acf()** to look for autocorrelation, etc.).